# change rgb dynamically in netlogo

Tags: dynamic, colors, rgb, netlogo

So I'm writing a short programme in net logo where I want to color code my turtles based on a variable that they own `view` which varies between -1 and 1. I tried using `color-scale` in netlogo to define the colour, but it doesn't do quite what I want.

I wrote this to describe what I want, but netlogo seems to be getting confused when I pass the `col` variable to the `set color` command.

```
to colorise;;------------------------------------------------------------
; this changes the agent's colour based on their current [view] score. 
; We could use the color-scale in netlogo, but it only works for one colour 
; and it's easy to end up with a colour so dark we can't see it against black patches. 

  moderate ; resets any agents which have somehow ended up with a view score outside -1 to +1
  ifelse view > 0 
  [ let col  ( 1 - view ) 
    set col col * 255
    set color [ 255 col col ]
  ]
  [ let col  ( 1 + view ) 
    set col col * 255
    set color [ col col 255 ]
        ]

end
```

does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Will

Comment: http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/faq.html#listexpectedconstant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have correctly limited the range of view, you will just run into a list creation problem: you cannot use the bracket notation with variables. Instead try

```
set color (list col col 255)
```

etc

Comment: Thanks! I'm just learning and I thought it'd just be something that's relatively easy to solve (just not for someone ignorant like me...)